# FIREBIRD BLR DECODER

Tags: firebird, interbase

folks. When i belived i was a genius and that metadata was my intelectual property, i developed a procedure  in firebird to track changes on a single table, something with id´s and time stamps. So, i´ve done a mega clever move and deleted the source of this procedure.

Does anyone knows a BLR decoder, or the doc´s that i need to build one?

TIA.

Comment: Would this apply to Interbase too? If so, you may want to edit that into your title and tags to attract more of the possible experts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen a BLR display tool (in Jason Wharton's IB admin tool), but it would only display BLR names, not transliterate back to SQL/proc language. I think what you're looking for doesn't exist.

You can [get BLR documentation here](https://web.archive.org/web/20060313133226/https://www.ibphoenix.com/downloads/blr_syntax.pdf), though.

Answer (score 4):

There is nice BLR (binary) to BLR (text) decoder in Firebird itself. You can enable it with `set blob all` (or `set blobdisplay all`). You can call it from ISQL:

```
SQL> set term !;
SQL> create procedure p1
CON> as
CON>   declare n integer = 1;
CON> begin
CON>   n = n * 2;
CON> end!
SQL> set term ;!
SQL> 
SQL> set blob all;
SQL> commit;
SQL> 
SQL> select rdb$procedure_blr from rdb$procedures where rdb$procedure_name = 'P1';

RDB$PROCEDURE_BLR 
================= 
             1a:3 
==============================================================================
RDB$PROCEDURE_BLR:  
            blr_version5,
            blr_begin,
               blr_message, 1, 1,0,
                  blr_short, 0,
               blr_begin,
                  blr_declare, 0,0, blr_long, 0,
                  blr_assignment,
                     blr_literal, blr_long, 0, 1,0,0,0,
                     blr_variable, 0,0,
                  blr_stall,
                  blr_label, 0,
                     blr_begin,
                        blr_begin,
                           blr_assignment,
                              blr_multiply,
                                 blr_variable, 0,0,
                                 blr_literal, blr_long, 0, 2,0,0,0,
                              blr_variable, 0,0,
                           blr_end,
                        blr_end,
                  blr_end,
               blr_send, 1,
                  blr_begin,
                     blr_assignment,
                        blr_literal, blr_short, 0, 0,0,
                        blr_parameter, 1, 0,0,
                     blr_end,
               blr_end,
            blr_eoc

==============================================================================
```

Comment: That facility appears to be in `isql` itself, not in the Firebird server (even those the `isql` is part of the Firebird package). In other words, you don't "call" it from `isql`, you display the BLR with `isql`. Very nice none the less, +1!

Comment: IBExpert also has BLR decoder, but AFAIR in some details it is different than iSQL's // @CosminPrund however the decoder is part of server itself. It is what IBM hyped about dozen years ago as "Data blades", in Firebird it is called "BLOB filters", as special badly documented case of UDF's designed to convert BLOBs into other data types (extraction of data from BLOBs would be a specific case of such conversion). Firebird server has a built-in "BLOB filter" ( aka "Data Blade" aka any other ex-buzzword ) and u can invoke it by ANY sql client.

Comment: Example: `select cast( rdb$trigger_blr as VarChar(2000) ) from rdb$triggers where rdb$trigger_name = 'CHECK_17' ` - and here you have it, even without iSQL or IBExpert

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the database there is a chance the procedure source is still there somewhere but marked as deleted. You may try to open the database file on a hex editor and search for the procedure name.